# SharePoint 2007 Create Calendar on every My Site

Tags: sharepoint-2007, calendar

When user access My Site I want that there is already created Calendar. Just the same as there is

- Personal Documents,
- Shared Documents
- Picture Library

How to Achieve this ? There must be same installation template ..
Thank you for answering.

Answer (score 0):

[Feature stapling](http://sharepointmagazine.net/technical/development/introduction-to-sharepoint-feature-stapling-part-1) might be an option.

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify the answer by Flo.
You need two features:

1. Creates an instance of a calendar list
2. Creates a feature stapling to bind the first feature to the personal site template

This will cause the list instance feature to be activated when a new my site is created

Answer (score 0):

See [Customizing MOSS 2007 My Sites within the enterprise](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepoint/archive/2007/03/22/customizing-moss-2007-my-sites-within-the-enterprise.aspx) (and, yes, it uses stapling).

Comment: i must say that .. sharepoint is truly the best !  .. i would just like to, that there would be calendar available on every my site site, and for that i will have to do double feature shit .. truly awesome